# Formatting data from an excel sheet in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, format, pivot-table

I import data from an excel file using the command `xlsread`. The data look like the following:

[image]

I would like to format these data so that the output looks like:

```
A = [NaN 1 2 3; 
    20160101 100 80 90; 
    20170101 150 90 200]
```

In excel, I would use a Pivot table. Is there an equivalent in MATLAB or how would I start to code this? Is `reshape` an option here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you are [reading your data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) from the file as follows:

```
data = xlsread('your_file.xls');
```

Which gives you a numeric matrix containing your data. You can then reorganize it by parsing your first and last columns using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), then using the results as indices into [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to collect the data in the center column. Then you just add the row and column labels:

```
[rowVals, ~, rowIndex] = unique(data(:, 3));
[colVals, ~, colIndex] = unique(data(:, 1).');
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 2));
A = [NaN colVals; rowVals A];
```

And the result, for your sample data above:

```
A =

         NaN           1           2           3
    20160101         100          80         200
    20170101         150          90         200
```

If you have duplicate entries (i.e. entries that have the same date and identifier), the above will sum them by default. You can provide a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) to `accumarray` if you'd like it to do something else. For example:

```
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 2), [], @mean);      % Averages them
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 2), [], @(x) x(1));  % Keeps the first entry
```

Comment: This answer is superb. I've one additional question to this matter (not sure whether I sould open a new question for that). What if there would be a duplicate? Let's say there are two values of 20160101 with a value of 100. Your code would build a sum of these two in the output (so it would be 20160101 200 80 200). Ideally it would leave it with 100.

Comment: @Joe: I added an explanation for how you can deal with duplicate entries.