# Formatting data from a csv file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, format, import-from-csv

I have a large `csv-file`, which looks similar to the following:

[image]

My problem is related to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209419/formatting-data-from-an-excel-sheet-in-matlab) previously posted and superbly answered by @gnovice. I am using the folling code to format the data.

```
data = csvread('datacsv.csv',1,0);
[rowVals, ~, rowIndex] = unique(data(:, 3));
[colVals, ~, colIndex] = unique(data(:, 1).');
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 2), [], @(x) x(1));  % Keeps the first value
A = [NaN colVals; rowVals A];
```

The output, however looks like:

[image]

It should ideally look like:

[image]

Whatis the part of the code that I have to adjust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date appears in the second column for this data, whereas it appeared in the third column on the previous question. Just change the index in the second line to a 2:

```
[rowVals, ~, rowIndex] = unique(data(:, 2));
```

And change the index for the accumulated data to a 3:

```
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 3), [], @(x) x(1));
```

Comment: The solution for this setting works perfectly well. Although not directly related to this question, could you please explain, why I obtain an error "Error using dlmread" - "Empty format string is not supported at the end of a file."? The real data are far larger, yet the csv-file looks the same as in the example above?

Comment: @Joe: Not sure. I couldn't find a way to recreate it. I'd check the last line of your file for extra whitespace.

Comment: Saving the large csv-file (1.875.150 KB), the data seem to get lost as the file then has 0 KB. I fixed it and your code performs very quick!

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use "unstack":

```
myTable = readtable( 'data.csv' );
newTable = unstack( myTable, 'C', 'A' )

newTable =

  3×3 table

        B          x1         x2   
    _________    _______    _______

    2.015e+07        NaN       -2.5
    2.016e+07    -2.5625       -2.5
    2.017e+07        2.5    -2.5625
```