# Formatting data from an excel sheet (two criteria) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, formatting, accumarray

I have a question related to [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209419/formatting-data-from-an-excel-sheet-in-matlab) recently asked. I download my data as a `csv.file`. I then format it in MATLAB. I obtan formatted data such as:

[image]

I would like to format the data so that I obtain:

[image]

In other words, the date should be in the first column, while the two identifier should be in the first two rows, respectively.

I tried the code provided by @gnovice, yet I have problems to adjust for the second identifier. The code is:

```
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 4), [], @(x) x(1));
A = [NaN colVals; rowVals A];
```

where `data` is equal to picture (1).

Therefore, I obtain a matrix `A` like:

```
 A = 
      NaN     1    2     3;
 20160101   100   80    90;
 20170101   150   90   200;
```

How can I adjust my code in a way that the second identifier is taken care of and `A` becomes:

```
 A = 
      NaN     1    2     3;
      NaN    10   10    15;
 20160101   100   80    90;
 20170101   150   90   200;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer from albusSimba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47628794/52738) points in the right direction. You'll want to collect the columns containing your identifiers (i.e. `data(:, [1 3])`), pass that to [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) with the `'rows'` option to find the unique row combinations, then capture the third output to use as the index for aggregation by [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html). Your final matrix formatting will then just have to be changed to account for the second identifier:

```
[rowVals, ~, rowIndex] = unique(data(:, 2));
[colVals, ~, colIndex] = unique(data(:, [1 3]), 'rows');
A = accumarray([rowIndex colIndex], data(:, 4), [], @(x) x(1));
A = [NaN colVals(:, 1).'; NaN colVals(:, 2).'; rowVals A];
```

And the result for your sample data:

```
A =

         NaN           1           2           3
         NaN          10          10          15
    20160101         100          80         200
    20170101         150          90         200
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
C = unique([identifier_1,identifier_2],'rows')
```

And format your data accordingly